# Transform Decimal Longitude / Latitude to UTM Easting / Northing across multiple projection zones

Tags: r, r-sp, rgdal

I have a large quantity of data (100k+ objects) describing incidents that took place across the African continent - location data is stored in Decimal longitude and latitude.

Given that this data spans many different projection zones, does anyone have any suggestions about how might I go about translating en-masse into UTM eastings / northings to facilitate the calculation of distances (in KM) between points in further analyses.

Any advice - greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain why conversion to UTM is required? The `geosphere` R package, for example, can calculate distances between points using longitude and latitude.

Comment: Ideally I need convert to e/n as I have a long subsequent analysis workflow that relies on UTM (I have previously applied these analyses to events that take place over a much smaller area and hence are all in the same projection zone and, by extension, easier to convert)